# Happy Sysadmin day

Tags: discussion

Happy sysadmin day to all you sysadmin guys. 
The occasion for you to see all the work you did, but moreover, all the passion and love we put into our so-much special job. Actually, since I'm a sysadmin, my life has taken a new complete turn, it's something you could never explain to someone who ain't. Ask for gifts guys

http://www.sysadminday.com/

Comment: Sweet, thoughtful, and much-appreciated, but not actually a question.

Comment: True, I'll use by now meta server fault for such topics thanks

Answer (score 9):

Happy Sysadmin day to all sysadmins all over the world :)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, Happy Sysadmin day! [And now make me a sandwich](http://xkcd.com/149/).

Comment: `Access Denied, this attempt has been reported`.

Comment: The correct spelling being "sammich"